# Crashed In NSArray init

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I got a crash log described as these:

```
Exception Type:  SIGABRT  
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x3b694350  
Crashed Thread:  0  

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[124]'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x3346e2a3 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation) + 163  
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3b19697f objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 31  
2   CoreFoundation                      0x333b834d -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] (in CoreFoundation) + 165  
3   CoreFoundation                      0x333c6559 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] (in CoreFoundation) + 45  
4   CoreFoundation                      0x333d0869 -[NSDictionary allKeys] (in CoreFoundation) + 261  
5   SogouInputIPhone.dylib              0x06707df1 0x66e2000 + 155121  
6   SogouInputIPhone.dylib              0x066e5533 0x66e2000 + 13619  
7   CoreFoundation                      0x333bf037 _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation) + 1427  
8   Foundation                          0x33cd5599 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation) + 73  
9   UIKit                               0x35301121 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] (in UIKit) + 817  
10  UIKit                               0x352771e7 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] (in UIKit) + 2459  
11  UIKit                               0x352766cd -[UIApplication sendEvent:] (in UIKit) + 73  
12  UIKit                               0x3527611b _UIApplicationHandleEvent (in UIKit) + 6155  
13  GraphicsServices                    0x36f8e5a3 _PurpleEventCallback (in GraphicsServices) + 591  
14  GraphicsServices                    0x36f8e1d3 PurpleEventCallback (in GraphicsServices) + 35  
15  CoreFoundation                      0x33443173 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation) + 35  
16  CoreFoundation                      0x33443117 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 (in CoreFoundation) + 139  
17  CoreFoundation                      0x33441f99 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 1385  
18  CoreFoundation                      0x333b4ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 357  
19  CoreFoundation                      0x333b4d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode (in CoreFoundation) + 105  
20  GraphicsServices                    0x36f8d2eb GSEventRunModal (in GraphicsServices) + 75  
21  UIKit                               0x352ca301 UIApplicationMain (in UIKit) + 1121  
22  MyApp                               0x0000f94b main (in MyApp) (main.m:26)  
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x3b5cdb20 start (in libdyld.dylib) + 0
```

I have check my code, no NSArray is used.It seems that the run loop was dispatch the touch event, and generate a NSArray, but I am not sure about it and what let to the crash.

Comment: Reason is mentioned in the crash log. "Attempted to insert nil object to the array". If you couldn't find that post the related code.

Comment: I check my code where used NSArray and not find insert `nil` to array

Comment: its probably a subclass of nsarray, check the code for places in where you are inserting objects into other stuff, and also post the code that is executed just before this crashes

Comment: Is the `SogouInputIPhone.dylib` from your app? This one is causing the crash, not your main app. If it is yours, you need to symbolicate those frames, then you'll know where the bug is.

Comment: No, the `SogouInputIPhone.dylib` is a Chinese Input Method. I'm doubting about it too, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert nil into an `NSArray`, if you want to put a placeholder object into your array you can use `[NSNull null]`. The solution to your problem is to find the nil object that you're attempting to insert and refrain from inserting it, or alloc/init it and then insert.

If you post the rest of your code we may be able to pinpoint the problem more specifically.